# deleting file with unlink function php

Tags: php, mysql, unlink, delete-file

This script is working for deleting from mysql database, but it's not unlinking from local directory files. Can anyone help to fix this script? Here's the script

```html
<?php 

include "../config/database.php";

 if(isset($_GET['kode'])){
 $id = (int) $_GET['kode'];
 $sql = "select * from anidata where id='$id'";
 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ){
  $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  //delete file
  $path = 'upload/'.$data['image'];
  @unlink($path);
  //delete from database
  mysql_query("delete from anidata where id='$id'");
 }
} 

header("Location: view.php");
 ?>
```

And thanks for helping anyway! :)

Comment: try full path instead of 'upload/'

Answer (score 1):

This File are no delete Because file store out side of `www` folder and wemp server only working inside `www` directory .If you want to upload image on desktop or any other folder out side `www` folder same Condection apply No Uploading Done You Get An  Error.

```html
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['kode'])){
 $id = (int) $_GET['kode'];
 $sql = "select * from anidata where id='$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ){
  $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  //delete file
  $path = 'upload/'.$data['image'];
  @unlink($path);
  //delete from database
  mysql_query("delete from anidata where id='$id'");
 }
} 

header("Location: view.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: the upload file is inside the htdocs folder man, and so all the script.

Answer (score 1):

First try this to check if your file is deleted from directory

```
  if( @unlink($path) ) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `anidata` WHERE id='$id'");
  }
```

If not deleted from your database, check your assigned path in php code !!

Comment: like i said on my post.. the script can delete from the database, it's only cannot unlink from the upload directory.

Comment: i think then you are not defining the correct path for unlinking folders.. if i'm not wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

use **unlink($path);** instead of **@unlink($path);**